# Jenkins/Hudson Build error

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

My build integration is failing due to the following:

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdPublisher aborted due to exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:213)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.Priority.valueOf(Priority.java:18)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.getMinimumPriority(HealthAwarePublisher.java:622)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.AbstractHealthDescriptor.<init>(AbstractHealthDescriptor.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdHealthDescriptor.<init>(PmdHealthDescriptor.java:25)
    at hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdResultAction.<init>(PmdResultAction.java:31)
    at hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdPublisher.perform(PmdPublisher.java:138)
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:338)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:27)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:705)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:680)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:658)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1459)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
[ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your build server up to date? There was a bug about this: see here  http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6877?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=139728#action_139728

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have "Publish PMD analysis results" checked in your job configuration, but Jenkins can't find the file with the analysis results.